# Pass array as attribute in blade custom component

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-components

I have defied a generic `input` component in Laravel like this:

```
//file: views/components/input.balde.php    
<input  @foreach ($attrs as $attr=>$val)
                {{ $attr }} = "{{ $val }}"
            @endforeach
            >
```

And I would like to use it as follows in blade templates:

```
<x-input :attrs="{{ ['type'=>'text', 'placeholder'=>"Search.."] }}" ></x-input>
```

the thing is when I pass an array object like the example above it seems to break the view, however when I send a variable like this:

```
@php
    $attributesArray = ['type'=>'text', 'placeholder'=>"Search.."];
@endphp    
<x-input :attrs="$attributesArray" ></x-input>
```

Is there a way to pass the array as is without having to create a variable and sending it so that I don't add unnecessary @php directive?

Answer (score 3):

Just pass in the array without the double curly braces `{{ }}`

```
<x-input :attrs="[ 'type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'Search...' ]" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
`<x-input :attrs="{!! [ 'type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'Search...' ] !!}" />`

Comment: unfortunately this gives an error: `syntax error, unexpected '<'`

Comment: its not working

Answer (score -2):

Hi if I understand right you want to get any array values in the string you just simply can do it but using implode.

```
<x-input :attrs="{{ implode($attributesArray , " ") }}" ></x-input>
```

and the $attributesArray variable is just a variable to be sent to the blade it a key value array

Comment: Interesting, however why can I send a variable as a variable in a component, but not send an array as a variable the same way? And what's the difference between sending the array name as variable and sending the array directly?